# Image shift after receiving via serial port

Tags: image, matlab, port, fpga, uart

I set a serial port in matlab to receive an image via UART. After receiving the image, I notice that the image sometimes shifts and sometimes not shift. As shown in figure, left part is the correct receiving result and right part shows the shift of the image.

[image]

The following is my code.Is there any suggestion to improve my figure?

```
clear all
close all
s = serial('COM3','BaudRate',115200, 'Parity','none','DataBits',8,'StopBits',1);
s.InputBufferSize=200000;
s.timeout=20;
fopen(s);
flushinput(s);
D=fread(s,[200,200]);
E=fread(s,[200,200]);
F=fread(s,[200,200]);
image_RGB(:,:,1)=D;
image_RGB(:,:,2)=E;
image_RGB(:,:,3)=F;
imwrite(image_RGB/256,'myimage.jpg','jpg');
imshow(image_RGB/256);
fclose(s);
fclose all;
```

Comment: can you increase `InputBufferSize` to `400000`?

Comment: Thx Yvon, the total bit of the image are 960000 bits and I have tried many inputbuffersizes such as 960000 or 400000 etc but it does not work. Due to my observation, I guess either the inputbuffer or the image merge process play the key.

Comment: it might be interesting if you use some other tools to capture the serial data stream. i think something is wrong with the transfer, not the matlab stuff. because as you said it's not always shifted, and from the picture i see a yellow band, it's like the transmitter side is giving wrong signal.

Comment: Thx Yvon, as you said, I had considered the idea. The transmitter is an FPGA board. In order to keep the transmission data from FPGA memory to matlab correct, I initialize the memory data as same as the image. But it also does not work. I am confused why the result is sometimes wrong but sometimes correct.....

Comment: so maybe you can extend the question to fpga + matlab?

Comment: umm.... if the behavior of FPGA is wrong, it is impossible to get the correct data. Thus I focus on the matlab code

Comment: but it's possible the tx buffer pointer is shifted, right?

Comment: maybe you can verify the fpga sequence by sending a known bit stream, like `ABCDEFG` in a sequence? If matlab can receive in the right order - always - then the problem is `imshow`

Comment: I do not noticed whether there is the tx buffer setting in FPGA. Maybe that is the reason why the image sometimes failed. I will take the advice into consideration. thx Yvon !!